# Modifying a Portable Class Library project on a machine where some platforms are not installed

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, portable-class-library

I have a PCL project which supports the following platforms:

- .NET 4.5
- .NET for Market Apps
- Windows Phone 8

The problem I encounter is; while I can work with the project on a computer where Windows 8 is installed (along with the Windows Phone 8 SDK), I am unable to build the project at all on any Windows 7 computer without the WinPhone8 SDK.  I am also unable to install the WP8 SDK because it requires Windows 8.  I can manually edit source files, but I cannot build the PCL project to verify there are no compiler errors.

What would be the "best" practice" for making changes to my PCL project on a computer where some platforms (like WP8) are not installed?  Should I manually remove those platforms for that local copy of the project, only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've now made this possible in Visual Studio 2012 Update 2. This installs the required Phone 8 support for portable down-level on Windows Vista and Windows 7.

Grab the latest CTP here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36833.

Answer (score 4):

We don't have a good answer for this right *now*. If you drop Phone 8 support (back to Phone 7.5 or completely) then you can, as you've noticed, build on Windows 7. The reason for this, is because Phone tools itself carries the Phone 8 support - and therefore as it cannot be installed on Windows 7, neither can the portable Phone 8 support.

However, we are looking into addressing this in a future Visual Studio update sometime next year and I've filed a user suggestion over visualstudio.uservoice.com: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3374340-allow-portable-libraries-targeting-windows-phone-8.

Please vote if you feel its important - customer feedback is valued extremely high while trying to figure out what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

One option is for you to support only the profiles 1-4 - these are available in the first generation of PCL tools - http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b0e0b5e9-e138-410b-ad10-00cb3caf4981

If you want to develop for more advanced features (e.g Linq2Xml) then you need to get the missing 'profiles' installed on to the win7 machine.

This may be as simple as upgrading to the PCL2 download - http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b0e0b5e9-e138-410b-ad10-00cb3caf4981/ - this should (I think) install the new profiles beyond 1-4

I hope the above works for you...

If not, then you'll need to browse to the reference assembly directory on your Windows 7 box and you'll need to manually copy the missing profiles across from Win8. For some reference on how the PCL reference assemblies work, take a look at some of the hacking we've done to get MonoTouch and MonoDroid building - http://jpobst.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/mono-for-android-portable-libraries-in.html and http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/using-portable-library-tools-for.html

---

One further thing you may find useful - the nuget package bringing await/async back to wp7.1 development - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/10/22/using-async-await-without-net-framework-4-5.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the input, but the PCL2 downloads are intended to bring Visual Studio 2010 up to compatibility with VS2012.  I use VS2012 on both the Windows 7 and Windows 8 machines; my issue has more to do with specific, after-market platforms needing to be installed.

Comment: I don't believe you need the platforms - I think you just need to check which Profiles are installed. MSBuild doesn't know about which platforms the PCL project supports - instead it just knows about which Profile it has to build against.

Answer (score 0):

> What would be the "best" practice" for making changes to my PCL
>   project on a computer where some platforms (like WP8) are not
>   installed? Should I manually remove those platforms for that local
>   copy of the project, only?

Your problem is the solution to your problem, you will be unable to work on the PCL project on Windows 7, because of the Windows Phone 8 SDK requirement itself.  Until the Windows Phone 8 SDK supports Windows 7 you have limited options unless you remove the platforms Windows 7 does not support.

Comment: This ended up being what I had to do.  I just opened the project in Windows 7, and "unchecked" the Windows Phone 8 platform, so that the rest would compile.

Comment: @BTownTKD - You might be able to get away with in the future using the Windows Phone 7.8 version of the SDK once its released.  Sadly no information has been released on what features within Windows Phone 8 will be supported by Windows Phone 7.8 exactly.  Still does not solve the underline problem, likely will be less of an issue, in the future I suppose.